# How to Deploy with a CDN?

Tags: cdn, ansible, cloudflare

I'm surprised I haven't found answers to this by Googling. I currently don't have any CDN and run my deploys through Ansible. I'm thinking of adding a CDN, but since cache is only invalidated on these intermittently, my understanding is that a deploy on my servers wouldn't change the static files served by my cdn for potentially hours. Of course, when I do a deploy, I'd like everything done as fast as possible, so if anything does go wrong (or right), I know about it immediately.

All of that said, how do I actually deploy to a CDN, telling it I'm serving some new set of static files now and that it should refresh these? Is there an Ansible module that does something like this, or an API for some CDN provider? I'd really like to avoid doing this manually on every deploy as [this](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-the-cloudflare-cache-purge-featur/) seems to imply for Cloudflare, for example.

Also, I'm currently using CloudFlare for other stuff, so sticking with them would be cool, but I'm willing to switch over to something else if it's better for my use case.

As an aside, this seems like a standard use case with a CDN, but I can't find much documentation or blog posts for how people regularly deploy to CDNs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you could do a purge/invalidate, but that's not the best. Really, you want to use a tool that compiles* your CSS/SASS/whatever, images into sprites, and compiles your JS. Finally, the tool should understand static hosting, which means it uses a unique url for each publish. That way you don't have to purge, which is expensive for a CDN to do.

Thankfully, there are tools that handle this. I'm aware of [Ruby's `asset-pipeline`](http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/04/24/asset-pipeline-for-dummies/), [Grails's `asset-pipeline`](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline), and [Python's `webassets`](https://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Depending how you build your code and bake your stack, you might use Ansible to upload/deploy the static assets, though most of them have the ability to deploy locally or to s3.

`*` I'm using "compile", though it's really "minify/munge/compress" or "preprocess" or whatever.

Comment: In simpler terms, instead of explicitly invaliding CDN whenever your content changes, you simply change filenames to have some sort of uniqueness based on file's content(such as append file hash).